# Too large fonts in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, fonts, outlook

When I open the following email in Outlook (save it as `email.eml`, and it can be opened by Outlook), the font size is too large. Because of `<span style="height:40px;">...</span>`, Outlook suggests to open the email in a browser. If I do so, the correct font size is used. The zoom setting in Outlook is of course set to 100%. How can I get Outlook to display the correct font size? I am going to send out a newsletter, and don't want everybody using Outlook to see a too large font.

```
Date: Wed, 6 Apr 2016 19:25:19 +0200
From: test@test.com
Message-ID: <e43845aa69c33b79a282f80ed658959d@www.test.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
To: test@test.com
Subject: Font size test

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>Font size test</title><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body><h1 style="font: 20px Arial">Heading 1</h1>
<p style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Georgia">The font size is too large in Outlook!</p>
<span style="font: 10px 'Times New Roman'; height:40px;">This is a span with height, to make Outlook suggest opening the email in a browser.</span> </body></html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the cause of the fonts being larger in Outlook: The "[Make text and other items larger or smaller](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/get-best-display-monitor)" setting was set to 125%.

This setting does not change the font size of the emails when viewing them in a Web browser, or even when using the built-in Windows 8 Mail App. Outlook 2013, however, scales the fonts of the email based on this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Rendering a newsletter in Outlook or via your browser is very different.

If you want to display it properly in your email client, you have to *code like it's 1999* and put everything inline.

To fix your `<h1>`, you should specify the styling way more than you're doing right now:

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal;line-height: 1; color: #000000;">Heading 1</h1>
```

for example.

Here are some articles to get you started and familiar with proper HTML email coding:

- [Coding your emails](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/) *How does it work?*
- [The Foundations of Coding HTML Email](https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic) *How does it work?*
- [Email Coding Guidelines](https://gist.github.com/janogarcia/4977a2346cbc7e52334b) *What to do?*
- [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) *What is supported?*